# How to support uncommon languages on Android without localized resources?

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

In the language preferences of Android, many languages show the remark "May not be available in some apps" (I assume these are languages for which Android itself is not localized). Norwegian Nynorsk is an example:

[image]

In an Android App, when accessing the list of preferred languages via

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().toLanguageTags();
```

these languages seem to be moved from the start of the list if the App does not contain localized resources for them. The same is not true for languages which do not have the remark in the Android settings.

As an example, given the configuration of the screenshot above, if the app contains a `values-nn` folder with a non-empty resource file, the preferred languages are returned as `nn-NO,en-US,it-IT`. If the app does not contain any resource folder with a Nynorsk specific language tag, the preferred languages are returned as `en-US,nn-NO,it-IT`. Essentially, US English is moved before Nynorsk.

Additionally, specifying the supported languages in the `resConfigs` section as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support#design) seems to have no impact on this behavior. When adding `nn` to this list without adding corresponding resources, the behavior remains unchanged.

This is relevant if an App uses a third party translation tool (e.g. Xamarin/.NET resource files) and does not have localized Android resources. If the App uses the common approach of displaying texts in the most preferred language, languages like Nynorsk would not be usable in the App. As a workaround, dummy resources can be added.

Given the Android behavior described above, I have the following questions:

1. Is there an option to specify which languages an Android App supports without using resource folders/files?
2. Does Android documentation exist regarding these languages and this behavior?